# How to enable grub loader to support multiple OS boot

Tags: windows-10, uefi, ubuntu-16.04

I have a lenovo laptop with windows 10 installed in UEFI mode. I wanted to install ubuntu OS and make the system a multiple OS boot system. I have installed the ubuntu OS by making a slight change in the BIOS. I have changed from UEFI mode to Legacy support mode and installed Ubuntu.

Now if I change the BIOS to UEFI mode, windows gets started. If I change the BIOS to Legacy support mode, Ubuntu gets started.

I want, when the laptop starts, it should prompt me an option as like which OS shall I login like the grub loader. How to fix this. Any help will  be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't install Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Comment: My bootable pendrive was not recognized under the UEFI mode. When I changed the mode from UEFI to Legacy support mode, the bootable pendrive worked and the Ubuntu got installed.